# How to access Data of a Column in a TreeView with Index

Tags: qt, indexing, treeview, qml, qtquick2

I want to access `Data` of a `Column` in a `TreeView` while  knowing `Index` but I have trouble to do it.

Here is an example. I want to change the value of `isCollapsed` when a row is `expanded`:

```
TreeView {
    id: view
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 300
    }
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Permissions"
        role: "filePermissions"
        width: 100
        delegate : MouseArea {
            id:mous
            property bool isCollapsed : false
        }
    }
    model: fileSystemModel

    onExpanded {
        index.data("filePermissions").isCollapsed = true //This is not working, I don't find the right syntaxe
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no way to do this. If you what to know whether the delegate is collapsed, use `styleData.isExpanded `. If you what to collapse one index when another index is expanded, use `view.collapsed(someIndex)`. Otherwise, you have to store properties in model instead.

Comment: This is how I fixed it at this time. But for me it is wrong to store these properties in the model because the model doesn't have to manage view problems. And this probleme is relative to Qml so if I use something else, this property might be deleted.